# Force at least one argument for rest parameter

Tags: arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, variadic-functions

I searched for an answer for this but did not find an answer:
Is there a way to force at least one argument for a rest parameter?
In the code below all three calls to `logArray` are valid but I want the first one to fail.

```
function logArray(...elements: number[]) {
    elements.forEach(x => console.log(x));
}

logArray(); // should fail but works
logArray(1);
logArray(1,2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution could be just adding a regular parameter in front of the rest parameter and concatenating it back in the function body like so

```
function logArray(e1: number ,...erest: number[]) {
    [e1, ...erest].forEach(x => console.log(x));        
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work because now you can't call the function with a spread operator. e.g. `logArray(...myNumbers)`

Comment: ^ exactly, which is very confusing for someone trying to use your function. It might be best to simply type it as a rest parameter and include a function that checks for at least one argument but also not exactly ideal

Comment: Well you guys have to remember that this answer is pretty much 6 years old and at that time the spread operator wasn't that much of a concern yet :)
As mentioned in the beginning, it is just one possible solution as of that time, so please feel free to write new answers - it's only going to help future readers coming along the way.